# Problem calculating the probability that the mean score is less than a certain value.

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

I'm quite new to statistics and I'm having some trouble solving this problem:

> An unbiased dice is thrown $70$ times. Find the probability that the mean score is less than $3.3$.

Here's what I did:

Let $X$ be the score from a single throw then $E(X)=3.5$ and $Var(X)=35/12$. Let $\overline X$ be the mean value for 70 throws then $E(\overline X)=3.5$ and $Var(\overline X)=\frac{35}{12 * 70}=\frac{1}{24}$. We can use the Central Limit Theorem to approximate $\overline X$ so $\overline X$ is approximately $N(3.5,\frac{1}{24}$). Now it's quite easy to find the probability that the mean is less that $3.3$ just standardize and plug into a calculator, but somehow this gives the wrong answer. Anyone got any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: The procedure is correct and I get a value for P(X<3.3) = 0.163593.

Comment: @satishramanathan I get that answer too, but the book I'm using says the answer is 0.155, could just be a problem on their side.

Comment: They are using continuity correction, let me work through the problem with Continuity correction and let you know the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(X<70*3.3) = P(z<\left(\dfrac{70*3.3-0.5-70*3.5}{\sqrt{\frac{70*35}{12}}}\right)$$
$$=0.155103$$

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. This helps with a lot of other problems too. One question though, instead of multiplying and doing all that can't we just make the continoutiy correction $\frac{1}{2n}$ where n is the sample size?

Comment: I think you could.